# Как сделать так, чтобы выделенную строку в TableView можно было менять?

Tags: java, javafx, swing

Начал изучать `javafx` для создания `GUI`. До этого учил `swing` В `swing` можно создать такую таблицу:

```
 private DefaultTableModel dataTableModel;
private JTable dataTable;

private Double valueOfX, valueOfY;

private ArrayList<Ellipse2D.Double> pointList = new ArrayList<>();


public void addDataInTable(){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)dataTable.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Vector<>());
    }


public void deleteDataFromTableRow (){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)dataTable.getModel();;
    model.removeRow(dataTable.getRowCount()-1);

}

public void clearDataTable(){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)dataTable.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
}
// в конструкторе класса

 dataTableModel =  new DefaultTableModel();
    dataTableModel.addColumn("X");
    dataTableModel.addColumn("Y");
    dataTable = new JTable(dataTableModel);
    dataTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(dataTable);

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();

    RowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
    ((TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>) sorter).setSortable(1, false);
    dataTable.setRowSorter(sorter);

    JPanel tableButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton addDataButton = new JButton("Добавить точку");
    JButton deleteDataButton = new JButton("Удалить точку");
    JButton clearDataButton = new JButton("Очистить таблицу");
    addDataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            addDataInTable();
              }
    });
    tableButtonPanel.add(addDataButton);
    deleteDataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            deleteDataFromTableRow();
        }
    });
    tableButtonPanel.add(deleteDataButton);
    clearDataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            clearDataTable();
        }
    });
    tableButtonPanel.add(clearDataButton);
```

В итоге получается что-то типа этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Специально добавил две новые строки. Двойным щелчком мыши по ячейке запускается возможность ее редактирования, то есть можно вписать туда значение.

Теперь таблица на `javafx`

```
  public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
  private TableView <PointOfGraphic> dataTable;
private   Button addDataInTableButton;
private   Button deleteDataFromTableButton;
private   Button clearTableButton;
private ObservableList <PointOfGraphic> pointObservableList;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
ddDataInTableButton = new Button("Добавить точку");
    deleteDataFromTableButton = new Button("Удалить точку");
    clearTableButton = new Button("Очистить таблицу");

    addDataInTableButton.setOnAction(this);
    deleteDataFromTableButton.setOnAction(this);
    clearTableButton.setOnAction(this);

    VBox vBox = new VBox();

    pointObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    dataTable = new TableView<>();

    TableColumn <PointOfGraphic, Double> XColumn = new TableColumn<>("X");
    TableColumn <PointOfGraphic, Double> YColumn = new TableColumn<>("Y");

    XColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("X"));
    YColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Y"));

    dataTable.getColumns().addAll(XColumn, YColumn);

    XColumn.setMinWidth(50);
    YColumn.setMinWidth(50);
    vBox.getChildren().add(dataTable);
    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.getChildren().add(addDataInTableButton);
    hBox.getChildren().add(deleteDataFromTableButton);
    hBox.getChildren().add(clearTableButton);

    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

    vBox.getChildren().add(hBox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox,500,500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private void addButtonClicked(){
    dataTable.getItems().add(new PointOfGraphic());
}

private void deleteButtonClicked() {

    dataTable.getItems().removeAll(dataTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
}

public void handle(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==addDataInTableButton){
    addButtonClicked();
    }
    if (e.getSource()==deleteDataFromTableButton){
        deleteButtonClicked();
    }
  }
}
```

В итоге получается такая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я выделяю строку в этой таблице, я не могу поменять значение координаты `X` или `Y`, как на `Swing`. Почему? И как можно это сделать? P.S. `PointOfGraphic`это просто наследник `Object` с двумя полями `Double X, Double Y` Ничего особенного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо для колонки переопределить [cellFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellFactoryProperty), в которой реализовать необходимое поведение.

Ниже пример приложения, на котором желаемое поведение работает.

```
public class TestJavaFx extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        TableView<Person> tableView = createTableView();
        pane.setCenter(tableView);

        Button print = new Button("Print table persons");
        print.setOnAction(event -> tableView.getItems().forEach(System.out::println));
        pane.setBottom(print);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableView<Person> createTableView() {
        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.getItems().addAll(new Person("Jack", 13), new Person("Steve", 25), new Person("Michael", 20));
        TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        nameColumn.setCellFactory(p -> new CustomTableCell<>());
        nameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
            String newName = event.getNewValue();
            Person person = event.getRowValue();
            person.setName(newName);
        });

        TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>("age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("age"));

        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, ageColumn);
        return tableView;
    }

    public static class Person {
        String name;
        int age;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return this.age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name + "[" + age + "]";
        }
    }

    private static class CustomTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T, String> {
        private TextField textField;

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            if (textField == null) {
                createTextField();
            }
            textField.setText(getString());
            setGraphic(textField);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getString());
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String s, boolean b) {
            super.updateItem(s, b);

            if (b || s == null) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            }
        }

        private String getString() {
            return String.valueOf(getItem());
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setOnKeyPressed(t -> {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || t.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Обратить особое внимание необходимо на метод `createTableView`, а конкретно на переменную `nameColumn`. Мы ей проставляем

1. `cellValueFactory` - для того, чтобы колонка знала, какую проперти из нашей модели отображать в ячейке
2. `cellFactory` - фабрика для отображения самой ячейки при редактировании
3. `onEditCommit` - мы обрабатываем event, который возникает, когда мы сохраняем значение в ячейке ( покидаем ее по enter или tab)

так же важно помнить, что еще необходимо выставить `tableView.setEditable(true);` иначе редактирование не будет работать.

после изменения имен, можно нажать кнопку "Print table persons" и тогда мы увидим в консоле, что значения имен поменялись (и сохранились) на новые

Comment: Странно, но когда я указал тип данных String при добавлении новой строки стал получать ошибку an not retrieve property 'first' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@109df7eb with provided class type: class CourseWork.PointOfGraphic
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read from unreadable property first

хотя тип данных везде поменял на String

Comment: А почему вы используете String, если в модельке лежат Double? Там для PropertyValueFactory очень важно,чтобы были методы гет/сет написаны по конвенции

Comment: @Andew Bystrov Я поменял мой Double на String в классе PointOfGraphic (в примере Person) TableColumn тоже теперь содержат строки. В общем везде, где нужно было заменил Double на String, чтобы использовать класс CustomTableCell без изменений. get/setX/Y теперь тоже стринговые. и получаю такую ошибку.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH судя по этому ответу https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037130/3452146 у вас все таки модель не совсем верная. Приложите полный код PointOfGraphic как есть ( со всеми модификаторами доступа), без изменений